# Got Error while accessing Active Directory from Web Service on Production Server

Tags: c#, web-services, active-directory, ldap

I got the following error message to connect to the Active Directory to get the User Info through web service.

**The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.**

However, if I run the webservice locally, it is ok and I could get the user info from the web service.

If I run the following codes in normal way (not webservice), it's working fine.  The problem only occurs if I changed it to the Web Service.  Any advice?  Thanks.

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetADUserInfo(string SAMAccount)
{    
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxx", "username", "pwd");

        try
        {
            string Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", SAMAccount);

            string[] properties = new string[] { "employeeid", "cn" };
            DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry, Filter, properties);

            SearchResult result = Dsearch.FindOne();

            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write("Err in GetADUserInfo : " + ex.Message);
        }


    return {"a","b"};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer.
Previously, My LDAP String is LDAP://DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=cc

Instead of that, I changed it to use the Domain name and it becomes like the following:

LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=cc

I am not sure it is the correct way or not.  But it works for me.  Suggestions and Advices are welcome.